# Skipping rows starting with specific values while importing a CSV file into R using FREAD

Tags: r, csv, fread

I am trying to import a `CSV` file from an `URL` in `R`. The file contains rows randomly starting with specific strings - either `'<<<<<<< HEAD', '=======' or '>>>>>>> master'`. The rows containing these characters are at random row locations.  I want to avoid these rows and import rest of the document. Is there a way to do? I prefer to use FREAD for importing the data. Appreciate inputs.

The data is not loading by default. It is throwing an error at the first instance (line 347 of the CSV) of encountering the aforesaid string. The URL from which I am trying to download the data is `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv"` and the error it is throwing is as follows:

```
[0%] Downloaded 0 bytes...
Warning message:
In data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv",  :
  Stopped early on line 347. Expected 7 fields but found 1. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<<<<<<<< HEAD>>
```

The the code statement that I am using to download the data is:

```
covid_ds <- data.table::fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv')
```

Comment: The documentation on FREAD doesn't provide details on this.

Comment: Usually for that you load the data into R and then clean it. Any reason you can't do that?

Comment: I have provided more info on the error I am facing. Please refer to the main question for the details. Thank you.

Comment: @QAsena, please see my updated post

Comment: @Ronak Shah, please see my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the data with `read.csv` with `fill = TRUE`, keep only those rows that have data in date format in `date` column so values like `'<<<<<<< HEAD'` or `'======='` are removed and use `type_convert` to change them in respective types.

```
data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv', fill = TRUE)
data <- data[grepl('\\d+-\\d+-\\d+', data$date), ]
data <- readr::type_convert(data)
data

#    date       province country       lat  long type      cases
#   <date>     <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <int>
# 1 2020-01-22 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 2 2020-01-23 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 3 2020-01-24 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 4 2020-01-25 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 5 2020-01-26 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 6 2020-01-27 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 7 2020-01-28 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 8 2020-01-29 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# 9 2020-01-30 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
#10 2020-01-31 NA       Afghanistan  33.9  67.7 confirmed     0
# … with 287,772 more rows
```

and with `data.table::fread` you can use `blank.lines.skip=TRUE`.

```
data <- data.table::fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/master/csv/coronavirus.csv', blank.lines.skip=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I find read.csv a bit slow downloading the data compared to fread. Wonder similar thing can be done in fread...

Comment: You can use `blank.lines.skip=TRUE` in `fread`. I updated the answer with that.